# Java Streams - how to add item to nested list

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to add an item to my nested list like below:

```
nestedProducts.get(3).getNestedProducts().add(
                newItem);
```

where nestedProducts = `List<Obj1>`

getNestedProducts() returns `List<Obj2>`

How to do that with streams? I want to add newItem to the object nestedProducts.get(3) with a defined optionType.equals(ABC)

I started with:

```
nestedProducts.stream()
                .filter(nested -> nested.getOptionType().equals("ABC"))
                .map(...)
```

what next? I don't have idea...

**UPDATED**

My updated code with forEach

```
 nestedProducts.stream()
                .filter(nested -> nested.getOptionType().equals("ABC"))
                .forEach(nestedProduct -> nestedProduct.getNestedProducts().add(newItem));
```

Comment: you already have code that works, _why_ do you need streams? and they are not designed for what you want to do here anyway

Comment: Because sometimes my Objects lies in the 2 index => nestedProducts.get(2) so I have to find the proper object in my nestedProducts list. It's a recursive list in list so only one type of my Objects with optionType = "ABC" can have nested products

Comment: Instead of `map`, you can use `forEach`.

Comment: A for-loop is perfectly adequate for solving this problem, and is probably going to be easier to read and debug.  Don't get me wrong, I love streams, but they're not always the right tool for the job, and aren't really something that you should always use just because you can.

Comment: Jacob - you're right, forEach is what I'm looking for:) Please see my updated code above - with forEach

Comment: @Matley now run your "solution" in parallel.

Comment: @Eugene - hmm, what do you suggest? That this solution may not work properly 
 in a multithreaded environment?